# Lotka-Volterra Problem From Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Problem 1 of section 2.7 of Arnold's [Ordinary Differential Equations](https://books.google.com/books?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC) book asks to prove that the period of the oscillations in the Lotka-Volterra model tends to infinity as the initial condition $(x_0,y_0)$ tends to $(0,0)$. The exposition is as follows: one begins with the Lotka-Volterra system

$$\dot x = kx-axy=(k-ay)x\qquad \dot y = -\ell y + bxy=(bx-\ell)y$$

Then one notices that this corresponds to a vector field in the phase space. One may rescale the vector field at each point $(x,y)$ to get a new system of ODEs

$$\dot x = \frac{x}{bx-\ell}\qquad \dot y = \frac{y}{k-ay}$$

and this system will have the same phase curves, up to re-parametrization.  Arnol'd then works with the latter system a bit to show that the solution curves are closed, but he never explicitly solves anything.

Here is the problem.  I know that the period of the oscillations for the latter system is $T=bx_0 + t_0$.  How do I relate this to the period of the oscillations of the former system, since the solution curves are reparametrized when passing from the former to the latter?

Comment: That depends: are both parametrizations uniform? In other words, when you rescaled the field, did you do so by the same factor at each point? If so, then the periods only differ by a constant factor.

Comment: @Ian No, you multiply everything by $\frac{1}{(bx-l)(k-ay)}$ to go from one system to another.  This is a different scale factor at each point on the phase space.

Comment: For every starting point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the positive quadrant, $\dot x(t)\leqslant kx(t)$ for every $t\geqslant0$ hence $x(t)\leqslant x_0e^{kt}$. In particular, $x(t)\leqslant \ell/b$ as long as $x_0e^{kt}\leqslant \ell/b$. Every solution curve in the positive quadrant must enter the domain $x\geqslant \ell/b$ hence the period $T$ of the solution curve passing by $(x_0,y_0)$ solves $x_0e^{kT}\geqslant\ell/b$. This proves that $T\to\infty$ when $x_0\to0$, uniformly on $y_0$. Similarly, $T\to\infty$ when $y_0\to0$, uniformly on $x_0$. The limit $(x_0,y_0)\to(0,0)$ is not required.

Comment: 1. This is Problem 1 in section §2.7 (not section §1.7). 2. The rescaled vector field mentioned above is unrelated to the solution of Problem 1 (and Arnol'd does not mention it as such). 3. Actually, the introduction of the rescaled vector field $(u,v)$ (our notations) solving $\dot u=u/(bu-\ell)$ and $\dot v=v/(k-av)$ is slightly odd for at least two reasons. 3.1. First, the solution curves in the $(u,v)$-plane are not solution curves in the $(x,y)$-domain of the original Lotka-Volterra system since, for example, no $(u,v)$-curve can cross the line $u=\ell/b$ .../...

Comment: .../... while every $(x,y)$-curve does. 3.2. Second, the Ansatz $(x,y)\to(u,v)$ is simply not used to find the $(x,y)$ solution curves. 4. Finally, Arnol'd very much *proves something*, namely, that the $(x,y)$ solution curves are exactly the level sets of the functional $bx+ay-\ell\log x-k\log y$ (see the quantity $p(x)+q(y)$ in the book).

Comment: @Did Thanks for the comments.  I understand how to do this now, and if you post an answer I would accept it.  However,  I have a few questions about your other points.  I think that Arnold is only showing $p(u)+q(v)$ give the level sets of $(u,v)$ to use your notation. The only connection to $x,y$ is his claim that the integral curves of $u,v$ and $x,y$ coincide.

Comment: Also ,with regards to reason 3.1, the system for $(u,v)$ is undefined on two lines meeting at the equilibrium point, but everywhere else the solution curves for $(u,v)$ and $(x,y)$ coincide, up to reparametrization of $t$.  I believe what Arnold means is that given $x_0=u_0,y_0=v_0$, there is a unique $\textit{continuous}$ curve in the phase space that satisfies the $u,v$ system where it's defined.  He shows that this must be a closed curve, then that means any solution for $x,y$ must be.  It's annoying that this was glossed over.

Comment: Again: the transform $(x,y)\to(u,v)$ is not necessary to show that the $(x,y)$ solution curves are the level sets of the function $p(x)+q(y)$. The solutions of the $(u,v)$ differential system are indeed confined to the level sets of the function $p(u)+q(v)$ but to *parts of these level sets* since each $(u,v)$ solution can at most span one quarter of such a level set because no solution can cross the lines $u=\ell/b$ and $v=k/a$. And finally, I fail to see where Arnol'd uses $(u,v)$ to show that $p(x)+q(y)$ is invariant along every solution $(x,y)$ of the original Lotka-Volterra system.

Comment: @Did I agree with everything you're saying, but I have no idea how you'd think to derive that $p(x)+q(x)$ is constant without first passing to $u,v$.  The whole reason Arnold defines $u,v$ is so that he can use separation of variables and equate the two integrals on the top of page 44 (in my edition) $\int \frac{k-av}{v} dv = \frac{bu-l}{u}du$ - where he uses $x,y$ instead of $u,v$.  You cannot use separation of variables on the original system.

Comment: The thing is that the system is "almost separable" (to use a non canonical term). To wit, if $(x(t),y(t))$ solves Lotka-Volterra then $dx=x(k-ay)dt$ and $dy=y(bx-\ell)dt$ hence $(bx-\ell)dx/x=(k-ay)dy/y$ (*Houston, separation completed...*), that is, $p(x(t))-p(x(0))=q(y(0))-q(y(t))$ where $(p,q)$ are the functions $p(z)=\int(bz-\ell)dz/z$ and $q(z)=\int(az-k)dz/z$, QED. The technique would apply to every system $\dot x=A(x)B(y)$, $\dot y=C(x)D(y)$.